# Mixing static and dynamic content in Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, static, spree

i'm new to the commerce solution Spree and want to realize a project with it. is it possible to mix dynamic content (e.g. products) with static content like static text, images etc.? like typical cms pages with products in a specific area on this page.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, maybe this extensions will help you:

[Static content](https://github.com/cmaujean/spree-snippets)

[Snippets](https://github.com/cmaujean/spree-snippets)

And you may read about view customization on [this](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/view_customization.html) page.